# How I can get the BI type site created in sharepoint online 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365

I have some excel data with multiple sheets, on which I need filtering and displaying the interactive reports to multiple web pages in SPO 2013.

For this I want to create a business intelligent site in sharepoint online 2013  to leverage the PPS(Performance point services, scorecards etc from BI features).

I don't see that option(while creation of site under enterprise tab -> Business Intelligent) available so far in sharepoint online.

though, on Prem if I go to central admin, I have this option, but I want to create this in SP OL.

**How I can get the BI type site created in SP OL?**

any other suggestions for this kind of requirements?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

They are present both in the Enterprise E3 subscription plan, and the Enterprise E1 subscription plan. Maybe they where not available when you posted the question seven months ago? Or it may be that you use a different subscription plan that don't have the BI-center site template?

[image]